# Report Viewer Horizontal Print

Tags: visual-studio-2010, printing, reportviewer

How do I do to print a table in my report viewer Horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the report designer, in the report properties page, set the Landscape orientation to Horizontal.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the property name, sorry :)